# how to get full url along with hash in capybara with phantomjs browser

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, capybara

I am scraping a page, and I opened it using capybara and phantomjs browser.

then i press a few buttons, submit a form and land up on a different page. I want to get the whole url along with the hash of this page. How can I get the whole url along with the hash?

For instance, suppose the full url with hash is http://www.exxxxample.com/hello?a=b&c=d#somestuff=87

It seems that I can only get the url without the hash part (somestuff=87) however it should be possible, since i have phantom. So is there a way to use phantom and some js code to read the hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url = page.evaluate(function(){
    return document.location.href;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Capybaras `current_url` returns the full current url including the "hash" (fragment)

```
sess = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist)
sess.visit("https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara")
sess.click_link('Drivers')
puts sess.current_url # => https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#drivers
```

If you need to extract just the fragment you can use URI::parse

```
URI::parse(sess.current_url).fragment
```